# Почему выпадает тире?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

> Он — человек неплохой, но себе на уме.
>
> Холодец — блюдо жирное и для
> меня вредное.

Почему при перестановке первых слов тире выпадает?

> Человек он неплохой, но себе на уме.
>
> Блюдо холодец жирное и для меня
> вредное.

Comment: Потому что тире перед прилагательным не обязательно: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92 (пункт 10).

Comment: Причём тут прилагательное?.. Перед прилагательным и так во всех моих примерах тире отсутствует.

Comment: Вообще-то, если переставляем второе слово, тире оказывается перед прилагательным. Надо было сказать, что тире тоже переставляете. Тогда пункт 6 в примечаниях. Честно говоря, тире там вообще немыслимо, никто бы там его не поставил, а вот перед прилагательным — другое дело. Вот притом.

Comment: Ага, понял логику. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этих примерах  мы меняем структуру предложения для более удобной постановки **логических ударений.** Это делается для подчеркивания нужного слова.

По правилам в разговорной речи или при инверсии тире может быть опущено, а также возможно дополнительное (интонационное) тире. Тире  не только обозначает паузу, но  и влияет на расстановку логических ударений.

**Вариант 1**

Примечание: сказуемым является сочетание «неплохой человек».

***Он — человек неплохОй**, но себе на уме.* Ударением выделено и подлежащее, и сказуемое.

***Он человек неплохОй**, но себе на уме.* При отсутствии тире ударением выделено только сказуемое (слово «неплохой»). Подчеркнуто качество человека.

***ЧеловЕк он неплохой**, но себе на уме.* Имеется в виду –  «как человЕк он неплохой».

**Вариант 2**

***ХолодЕц — блюдо жИрное** и для меня врЕдное.*  Ударением выделено и подлежащее, и сказуемое.

Или без тире: ***Холодец блюдо жИрное** и для меня врЕдное.*  Ударением выделено только сказуемое.

***БлЮдо холодец жИрное** и для меня врЕдное.*
Имеется в виду – холодец в качестве блюда, как блюдо.  Такой вариант обычно не используется, так как сложен для восприятия на слух. Можно подумать: «блюдо холодец»  –  это сочетание приложение + определяемое слово.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
У Розенталя сказано ещё: "Тире перед сказуемым-прилагательным ставится <...> при логическом или интонационном членении предложения". Верно ли я понимаю, что интонационное тире допустимо в данном случае: "Блюдо холодец — жирное и для меня вредное"?

Comment: Да, верно, перед прилагательным можно поставить интонационное тире. В устной речи надо четко поставить ударение. (1) Блюдо холодЕц — жирное и для меня вредное (это маловероятно, здесь  приложение "блюдо" обычно лишнее в разговорной речи.  (2) БлЮдо холодец — жирное и для меня вредное (= холодец как блюдо).

Comment: Получается, что здесь подлежащее в середине сказуемого?